# Mercado Pago only CreditCard

Tags: php, arrays

I'm learning Mercado-Pago SDK...

I'd like to only be able to use credit card's, and for that I'm trying to use, **"excluded_payment_types"**, so my array looks like this:

```
$preference_data = array(
    "items" => array(
        array(
            "title"         => "Puppy Dalmata",
            "description"   => "Nice description of the item",
            "quantity"      => 1,
            "currency_id"   => "MXN",
            "picture_url"   => "http://domain.com/dal2.jpg",
            "unit_price"    => 1500,
            "payment_methods" => array (
                "excluded_payment_types" => array ( 
                    "id" => "ticket",
                    "id" => "bank_transfer",
                    "id" => "atm",
                    "id" => "debit_card",
                    "id" => "account_money"
                ),
                 "installments" => 12

            ),
        )
    )
);

$preference = $mp->create_preference($preference_data);
```

With that I'm able to get the URL so that I can process the payment for that item, so, this is working "fine" the client is able to see how much is going to pay and a lot of option to make a payment:

Bank Deposit, Account Money, Debit card, Payment via "7Eleven, OXXO, STRIPES" and Credit card... the idea is to only show Credit Card and nothing else, the user can only select the type of card, Visa Credit or Master Credit ... and nothing else...

but as in the this url shows :https://api.mercadolibre.com/payment_types it doesn't work base on my ARRAY... so I wonder what am I doing wrong? ...

I thank you for any help you can provided

Thank you for taking the time to read my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

toke me some time to get back to this... anyway, the problem with that array is that I have the key **"payment_methods"** inside key **"items"** which is wrong... it should be outside key items ... and that solved to problem of getting "payment_methods" to only accept credit card... btw, after I solved this issue I went back to read and learn more about "**mercadopago**" API for processing online payments and is quite easy to use I'm not saying is better than... PayPal, but, yes more easy to use...